# How to loop over strong params when creating associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not to be confused with looping over params, how to loop over strong params?

There are a lot of "moving" parts to my code but I'll stick to the title of this post. I send an array of objects to the api as

```js
name: 'Foo',
tax_rate_component: {
  components: [{name: 'cgm', rate: '2'}, {...}]
}
```

In ruby, a `tax_rate` has many `tax_rate_components` (accounting). The incoming will create a `tax_rate` then its `tax_rate_components`. This is what works:

**Rails Controller:**

```rb
# We'll assume all required data are passed and no errors are thrown
def create
  tax_rate = @organisation.tax_rates.build(rate_params)
  tax_rate.save # Would be in an "if" statement

  create_tax_rate_components(tax_rate) # We skip the error checking
  render json: tax_rate, include: [:tax_rate_components]
end

  private

  def find_organisation
  end

  # Somewhere inside here I need to be using rate_component_params
  def create_tax_rate_components(tax_rate)
    components = params[:tax_rate_component][:components]
    components.map do |tc|
      tax_rate.tax_rate_components.build(
        name: tc[:name],
        rate: tc[:rate]
      ).save
    end
  end

  def rate_params
    params.require(:tax_rate).permit(:name)
  end

  # I need to use this
  def rate_component_params
    params.require(:tax_rate_component).permit(
      components: [[:name, :rate]]
    )
  end
```

I need to be using `rate_component_params` when creating the `tax_rate_components`, but how? Is there a clean way to create the `tax_rate` and its `tax_rate_components` using the strong params?

Looking back on all of my side projects, I never seem to use the strong param method when looping :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
def rate_component_params
  params.require(:tax_rate_component).permit(
    components: [:name, :rate]
  )
end
```

When you pass an array of symbols Rails will permit a hash with those keys. Rails also has a built in method of creating nested records from parameters - namely [`ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). For example:

```
class TaxRate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tax_rate_components
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tax_rate_components
end
```

This creates a setter named `tax_rate_component_attributes=` that takes an array of hashes and will create the records. It also takes care of a lot of the problems with your solution like wrapping the whole thing in a single transaction and updating/deleting.

If your API is "locked" and you can't change the signature you can modify the params or create a special setter so that they are passed to the nested attributes setter.

```
def rate_params
  params.permit(
    :name,
    tax_rates_component: {
      components: [:name, :rate]
    }
  ).tap do |p|
    attrs = p.dig(:tax_rate_component, :components)
    if attrs 
      p[:tax_rate_component_attributes] = attrs
      p.delete(:tax_rate_component)
    end
  end
end
```

With that you can get rid of the whole `create_tax_rate_components` boondoggle.

```
def create
  tax_rate = @organisation.tax_rates.new(rate_params)
  if tax_rate.save
    render json: tax_rate, include: [:tax_rate_components]
  else
    head :unprocessable_entity # or whateveer
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. You've missed a "comma" after `:name` and `tax_rate_component_attributes` should be `tax_rate_components_attributes`. All is well.

Comment: I can never seem to remember how nested attributes should be pluralized...